# Getting error in truffle migrate

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I am trying to compile a sample solidity contract,**sampleapp.sol**. The code is given below:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

The migration code is given below:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

The code for migration code js is given below (file `1_initial_migration.js`):

```
var sampleapp = artifacts.require("./sampleapp.sol");
const Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(sampleapp);
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

The error i am geting is: [image]

I am making this app over Eleven01 protocol. I have added their custom RPC in the Metamask.
Please let me know if you require further details.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should keep the name of the file consistent with the contract name.
**sampleapp.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Sampleapp {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kartikey yeah,NP!

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in [truffle documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#migration-files) your should create a new file for each migration.

But i think your main issue come from the `./` in your migration file.

Try like that.

**1_initial_migration.js**

```js
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

**2_sampleapp_migration.js**

```js
const sampleapp = artifacts.require("sampleapp.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(sampleapp);
};
```